# Publish shell script to artifactory from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins-plugins

Unable to publish shell script to artifactory from Jenkins plugin "Deploy artifacts to Artifactory".
If we need to publish jar and shell script, then what should be Include Patterns value?

[image: Include Patterns?]

Comment: You should package that shell script into a jar/zip...the question is why you need to deploy a shell scriptin to artifactory?

Comment: It's a client requirement.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the client requirement?

Comment: It is to upload sh file to artifactory. Since it is not getting possible, now client is willing to upload it manually.